# Why im getting this error pos 14: '!path.contains('//')': a document path must not contain "//"

Tags: firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-video-player

Im trink to figure our why im getting this error

```
VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:cloud_firestore/src/collection_reference.dart': Failed assertion: line 60 pos 14: '!path.contains('//')': a document path must not contain "//"
#0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:46:39)
#1      _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:36:5)
#2      CollectionReference.doc
package:cloud_firestore/src/collection_reference.dart:60
#3      _VideopageofcurrentuserState.likevideo (package:wichtigdenyady/taking%20videos/currentuservideos.dart:50:63)
#4      _VideopageofcurrentuserState._buildBody.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:wichtigdenyady/taking%20videos/currentuservideos.dart:417:24)
#5      _InkResponseState._handleTap
package:flutter/…/material/ink_well.dart:991
#6      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback
package:flutter/…/gestures/recognizer.dart:182
#7      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp
package:flutter/…/gestures/tap.dart:607
#8      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp
package:flutter/…/gestures/tap.dart:296
#9      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture
package:flutter/…/gestures/tap.dart:267
#10     GestureArenaManager.sweep
package:flutter/…/gestures/arena.dart:157
#11     GestureBinding.handleEvent
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:385
#12     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:361
#13     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent
package:flutter/…/rendering/binding.dart:278
#14     GestureBinding._handlePointerEventImmediately
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:316
#15     GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:280
#16     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:238
#17     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:221
#18     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1370:13)
#19     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1265:19)
#20     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1170:7)
#21     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:180:10)
#22     PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:276:7)
#23     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:96:31)
```

What I do is this :
First giving the method some data

```
buildBody(videos.data()['likes'],videos.data()['videourl'])
```

And then inside the method doing this

```
  Widget _buildBody( videoid,video) {
   

    return Container(
      - - - -
Stack(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(3, 7, 0, 0),
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                      child: RatingBarIndicator(
                        rating: _userRating,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) => InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                            setState(() {
                              _userRating = index + 1.toDouble();
                            });
                            print(index + 1.toDouble());
                            print(video);
                            likevideo(video, _userRating);
                          },
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.star,
                            color: Colors.amber,
                          ),
 ---
```

So on Rating bar tapping im calling the method like video that looks like that

```
 likevideo(String id, double _rating) async {
    String uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid;
    DocumentSnapshot doc =
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('videos').doc(id).get();
    if (!doc.data()['likes'].contains(uid)) {
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('videos').doc(id).update({
        'likes': FieldValue.arrayUnion([uid]),
      });

      FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('videos')
          .doc(id)
          .collection("uservotes")
          .doc(uid)
          .set({'videoid': id, 'rating': _rating, 'uid': uid});
    }
  }
```

Here im saving the current uid of the user uid  into the array and also saving id,_rating and uid into sub collection.
I dont know what the error means but I think it means that the path so this value

```
videos.data()['videourl']
```

is empty but its not when printing it it give me this

```
flutter: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/wichtigdenyag.appspot.com/o/allvideos%2F269700204266546905SaQFz?alt=med......
```

So where does the error cased from ???
But thats what I think maybe anyone knows what's really wrong

Comment: What are the values of `id` and `uid`? It looks like it's the `doc` function that is throwing the exception, so we really need to know those values.

Comment: check the code you can see that I call likevideo() and give that method the string video and double _rating . video is the link that I was showing you and the uid is the current user id its a string in that case this one 4Ceq1VY4pRcfZ2dHfzRUq8vMl5B2

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a repost of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67305397/

Comment: In other words, you're trying to use a URL as a document ID. You can't do that, for exactly the reason in the error message. (And note that instead of saying "check the code" it would be better to just make the question clearer... and ideally shorter. Any time you can provide a [mcve], that's really useful.)

Comment: Ok I found the error but im getting a similar problem here maybe you can check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67291134/unhandled-exception-type-string-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-liststring

Answer (score 1):

As you will see [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#collections_documents_and_fields) in the Firestore doc, document IDs cannot contain a forward slash (/).

So if you pass the string `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/...`to the [`doc()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/CollectionReference/doc.html) method returns an error like theone you get: `a document path must not contain "//"`.

Comment: i fix it but im getting a similar problem here maybe you can check out  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67291134/unhandled-exception-type-string-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-liststring